# Why does .net web service response binary data?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I got this kind of response when consuming .net webservice in my asp.net website sometimes, causing a "Response is not well-formed XML." exception.
Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

�      �TMo�0��W>m�Hq��'��(���v�d&`K�$�ɿ���!�ɦH�G>R�w�� Gp^[�F1]G���6�4��~u�    ���9Ba+ �e|2�QB�0�U�����Zw`�à.�EC��gSV�4���7�u̾==�t@s��s�J�Q��~��y��Ⱥ���vbt��Ch���N
��Zp6��)>8E�
8��I�*�D���d��nM%�;��E��[�����9��1��^�v@�{��ts{��F]�g�Ü�l��1�����~@�
=���_�D��mC�-����@���V@B�=q������ `�c
�A��*���F2�Cp(I8W�F�ǝ�K�8:�M��ZЙq`KQg�~>*)�9����[V��b�U�قA�i`���    �P!��b����i�����4l�k�~ȗ�]����Z�������͍�MM�~���M�[�,�'��z�\YI��+U���
U��d��}��l������Z�a�ݿp���Y����;�

Comment: Is this a WCF Service? or a Standard Web Service?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons:

- You are not sending the right content-type header with the xml
- You are not sending XML (binary/JSON)
- Your output stream is gzip/deflated encoded

It is not possible to tell which from the data you provided. Can you post your web service code, in particular where it sends the response back to the browser?